# m2eclipse: automatic Maven install upon build of dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a feeling I'm missing something very basic. Usually such feelings turn out to be justified. I am not very well-versed with Maven so bear with me please.

Using Eclipse Juno and m2eclipse, with an external Maven 3.0.4 install. I have two projects, `A` and `B`. Project `A` depends on project `B` for compilation. Both projects are packaging=`jar`. Simple.

Now, I right-click project `A` and choose *Run As -> Maven install*. This results in an error, with Maven telling me that it couldn't find project `B` in the repository.

Makes sense. Project `B` isn't in the repository. However, I would expect m2eclipse to detect that, and perform `mvn install` on `B` before attempting `A`.

This doesn't happen. `mvn install` on project `A` assumes that project `B` is already in my local repository. I have workspace resolution turned on.

What gives?

Comment: @chad, I am not sure why you edited my question's title. Your edit doesn't reflect *at all* what I was asking. I will revert back.

Comment: I see.  Sorry about that.  You could use the maven multi-module build structure to make sure that the dependency get's built when  you build your project.  But that may be more linking of the two than you want

Comment: Seems like the only way to go about it. I find it strange, though, from a usability perspective. Regardless of a multi-module structure: if a project is built in Eclipse, I expect a snapshot to be automatically installed into the local maven repository, so a following "mvn install" will just work.

Comment: There's more than just one or two oddities to the m2eclipse integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parent project to A&B.
Run 'mvn install -pl A -am' on parent project, and project B will be made (install) before project A.

Comment: How do you identify the project? I'm trying to run this command, but I keep getting `[ERROR] Could not find the selected project in the reactor:<my project>`